# How to reinstall or fix Python interpreter for XCode lldb?

Tags: python, xcode, macos, lldb

I got this message at XCode after deleting some system files.

```
(lldb) script
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'run_python_interpreter' is not defined
```

P.S. Had to reinstall XCode, but I've got same message at debugger after reinstalling IDE

Terminal output

```
$ lldb                                               
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 52, in <module>
    import weakref
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
```

Comment: What version of macOS and Xcode are you using and what system files did you delete?

Comment: @Tobi macOS 10.13.6,  xcode 9.4.1, maybe I had deleted some related with  lldb and python folders... Can't remember which folders i've deleted .

Answer (score 0):

You have a local installation of python on your computer (in `/usr/local/Cellar`).  There's a problem when you have two different pythons on your system; lldb links against `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` but that python somehow ends up using the python libraries from your installed copy instead.  I saw someone work around this once but I forget if it was by putting their local python last in `$PATH` or if they un-set their `$PYTHONPATH` before starting lldb.